# How to check compiler log in sql developer?

Tags: logging, oracle-sqldeveloper

I get this error:

> Errors: check compiler log

How can I see compiler log in Oracle SQL Developer?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

control-shift-L should open the log(s) for you.  this will by default be the messages log, but if you create the item that is creating the error the Compiler Log will show up (for me the box shows up in the bottom middle left).

if the messages  log is the only log that shows up, simply re-execute the item that was causing the failure and the compiler log will show up

for instance, hit Control-shift-L
then execute this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST123() IS
BEGIN
VAR := 2;
end TEST123;
```

and you will see the message "Error(1,18): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:          current delete exists prior "

(You can also see this in "View--Log")

One more thing, if you are having a problem with a (function || package || procedure) if you do the coding via the SQL Developer interface (by finding the object in question on the connections tab and editing it the error will be immediately displayed (and even underlined at times)

Comment: thanks for your anwser mainly the connections part. But isn't working yes. I'm using 2.1.1.64 version. Which version are you using?

Comment: Note: i'm creating a procedure

Comment: @Topera , I am also on 2.1.1.64.  when you go into the connections-->procedures-->[your procedure here] and make change and save it does not automatically open up the Compiler log @ the bottom?  (that's how it works for me).  is it possible that it is at the bottom of the screen and just hiding a bit? ( http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/plsql_debug/images/crproc12.gif -- from Oracle site)

Comment: @Topera hit enter too soon, what happens when you press Control-Shift-L?

Comment: when I opened the procedure and compile it works! I just don't works when I run sql in worksheet. Tks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

I can also use

> show errors;

In sql worksheet.

Answer (score 8):

To see your log in `SQL Developer` then press:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on macOS)

or

> View -> Log

or by using mysql query

> show errors;